# htaccess: why final page has GET parameters from start redirect page?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} someGetParameter=1
RewriteRule ^someoldpage.php$ http://newdomain.ru/page/ [L,R=301]
```

After redirect I get

```
http://newdomain.ru/page/?someGetParameter=1
```

instead of

```
http://newdomain.ru/page/
```

Why it is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s going ‘wrong’ because your assumption is wrong, see [`RewriteRule` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> **Modifying the Query String**
>
> By default, the query string is passed through unchanged. You can, however, create URLs in the substitution string containing a query string part. Simply use a question mark inside the substitution string to indicate that the following text should be re-injected into the query string. When you want to erase an existing query string, end the substitution string with just a question mark. To combine new and old query strings, use the `[QSA]` flag.

So:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} someGetParameter=1
RewriteRule ^someoldpage.php$ http://newdomain.ru/page/? [L,R=301]
```